# CSS Transform Property split page down the middle

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to split my page diagonally down the middle using the CSS transform (-45deg) property to achieve the following look.[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using an image that already has the 45 degree angle you want?

Comment: I plan to use parallax scrolling with this.

Comment: Ok, and the angle is going to change? Still not sure why you can't just generate a tilted image. Can you give me more information about you decision so that we understand the requirements?

Comment: @MG1 You need to provide more information about why you want to do this / your use case or it's hard to give a proper solution.  You could do this with a PNG and avoid CSS altogether and still use parallax effects.  Or you could use CSS3 transform... or CSS3 triangles.  Or gradients.  Or even JS.  We need more context about how it will behave and preferably a look at the markup as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if its the right decision to use only CSS.  But I plan to have the user scroll up or down and in each instance either the grey or pink part will get smaller and the content will change.  But the splitting line will remain diagonal.  At the moment I have the pink textured part as a background image on the body and the grey part is separate div that's rotated -45deg. Here it is http://hide.my/smx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this [demo](http://jsbin.com/nogup/1/edit) ?

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e0dedf 50%, #e37d72 50%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%,#e0dedf), color-stop(50%,#e37d72));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e0dedf 50%,#e37d72 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e0dedf 50%,#e37d72 50%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e0dedf 50%,#e37d72 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e0dedf 50%,#e37d72 50%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0dedf', endColorstr='#e37d72',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code shows a example of what u are trying to achieve:

```
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://freewallpic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Red-Leaves-HD-Wallpaper.jpg);
}

#triangle-topleft { 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 100px solid gray; 
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Check the jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/w5FQR/1/

I hope this explains enough. I also assume there are other solutions to this. Maybe this one will fit for You. Change the content of colors and image with yours.